# Losing styles when adding a User Control to a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio, user-controls

In my project, I am trying to add a button collection user control to an input based user control.  The button uc is going to be added to numerous other controls.  The problem that I've encountered is that the button uc is losing whatever css styles that I've attach to it, once it is added to the parent uc.  Initially, I had a panel on the parent that would add the button uc when the page was loaded, then I would add the button uc to the panel:

`(panel.controls.add(uc)`

This did not work, the styling of the buttons were lost. Next, I tried to set the positioning to the button uc and add it directly to the form:

```
static void SetLocation(Usercontrol uc) {uc.Attributes.add("style","left:425px;top:420px;"); }   
public void SetPage() { button = (uc)LoadControl(button.ascx); SetLocation(buttonuc); this.Controls.Add(buttonuc); }
```

But, this did not work either, it did not even locate the control properly.  My style sheet is already added to the parent uc, and the button uc to be added has its style on that sheet. I don't want to have to manually add the buttons to each uc parent.  Thank you for any help. I sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I've yet to come upon a similar issue in a search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is good practice to keep your styles separate from the markup.  This makes maintenance easier and it also saves yourself from searching for the reason one of your elements appears a pixel away from where you are expecting (for example... Similar issues can be exasperating).

Do you have the same issue if you set the CssClass attribute for your button(s) and set the styles in a css file for the class?

Comment: The styles for the button(s) are set within a css file.  Once they're added to the form, all of the styling for the buttons is lost. If I add them to a preexisting panel, at least they'll be in the right spot, but, without styling.

Comment: Are you using an ID selector to reference the button or a class?  When the button is added to page the ID is likely changing to ensure uniqueness so an ID selector wouldn't work.

Comment: Within the button uc markup, I essentially have: ID="btnAdd" CssClass="ButtonStyle"......

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that another style is overriding the desired styles from your CSS file.  I'd mess around with Firebug and see if you can come up with a more specific selector to target the buttons with.  For example, you could use "parentelement .class" in an attempt to make a more specific selector than whatever may be overwriting it.

Comment: I found out the problem, it was the damned default Microsoft master page styling that was overriding the styling I had for all of my controls, not just the buttons.  Sorry, to bring this back from the dead, I hadn't been on the site in a while.  Don't depend on the default master page, Never Forget.